# Why we can't compare two fields in SOQL where clause

Tags: soql

Let's say we have a query

```
select id,
    history_contact__r.last_seen__c,
    request__c
from history__c 
where lot__r.active__c = true 
and history_contact__c = '0031y000004Kr1AAAS'
and history_contact__r.last_seen__c < request__c
```

but result is:

> 'Unknown error parsing query'

Why we cannot compare two fields directly and have to use parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax was not supported when building out the query language. Outside of that design team, few people will be able to answer the "why" of that question. However, the **common workaround** is to simply implement a formula which does the comparison for you, then filter on that formula instead.

For example, your formula syntax would look like:

```
history_contact__r.last_seen__c < request__c
```

And then your query would just change to:

```
AND History_Contact__c = '003...'
AND My_Descriptive_Field_Name__c = true
```

Comment: Does it mean that I have to create formula field in history__c object?

Comment: Yes. You have to put the formula on your child object in this case.

Comment: Thanks, but what about this workaround? DateTime lastSeen = (DateTime)[select last_seen__c from Contact where id= :contact limit 1][0].last_seen__c; And then (in query) -   and request__c >= :lastSeen

Comment: If you want to add more code and queries to work around the problem, it may be viable. But that sort of approach wouldn't work from a pure SOQL standpoint.